# Snap.svg - Select second text element?

Tags: css, svg, snap.svg

How can I select the second `text` element?

I tried doing something like:

`.node text:nth-child(2)` but either I'm missing something or it's not working.

I'm using Snap.svg to add text to an element.

`element.text(x, y, 'text');`

According to the docs, there isn't a way to add a class to the text element.

Comment: try `.node text:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: @Aziz, that worked.  Now I understand.  I was selecting the second child rather the second text element.  Please an answer post for credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector works between direct siblings, meaning that if the children are not next to each other in the DOM, it will not work. In this case, we can use `:nth-of-type()` which is less strict and would target the next matching element regardless of DOM interruption (see demo).

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child):

> The :nth-child(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has an+b-1 siblings before it in the document tree, for a given positive or zero value for n, and has a parent element. More simply stated, the selector matches a number of child elements whose numeric position in the series of children matches the pattern an+b.

---

**Demo of `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type`:**

```css
.node {
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  border:5px solid #FFF;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.text, p {padding:1em;margin: 0; background: #000; color:#FFF;}

.node .text:nth-of-type(3) {
  background:green;
}

.node .text:nth-child(3) {
  color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="node">
  <div class="text">.text 01</div>
  <div class="text">.text 02</div>
  <div class="text">.text 03</div>
  <div class="text">.text 04</div>
</div>

<div class="node">
  <div class="text">.text 01</div>
  <div class="text">.text 02</div>
  <p>p</p>
  <div class="text">.text 03</div>
</div>
```

As you can see in the demo, the left side has a series of identical children, and in the right side they were interrupted by a `<p>` tag. The green background applied by `:nth-of-type(3)` works in both examples while `:nth-child(3)`'s yellow color did not work because of the interruption.

Further reading:

- [CSS-Tricks - The Difference Between :nth-child and :nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)
- [MDN :nth-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- [MDN nth-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)